# Compatibility condition on $f$ in initial boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Question:- Determine the solution of the initial boundary-value problem
$$u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx},~~~~~~0<x<\infty,~~t>0,~~~~~(1)$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x),~~~~~~~0\leq x<\infty,~~~~~(2)$$
$$u_t(x,0)=0,~~~~~~~0\leq x<\infty,~~~~~(3)$$
$$u_x(0,t)+h u(0,t)=0~~~~~~~t\geq 0,~~~h=\text{constant}~~~~~(4)$$
State the compatibility condition of $f$.

Answer:- Using characteristic curves, $\xi=x+ct,~\eta=x-ct$, we obtain
$$u(x,t)=\phi(x+ct)+\psi(x-ct)~~~~~(5)$$
from $(2)$, $f(x)=u(x,0)=\phi(x)+\psi(x)~~~~~(6)$

from $(3)$, $0=u_t(x,0)=c\phi'(x)-c \psi '(x)~~~~~(7)$

Using $(5), (6),$ and $(7)$, for $x>ct$, the solution to $(1)$ is given by
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x+ct)+f(x-ct)\right).~~~~~(8)$$
Now, for $0<x<ct$, we use boundary condition $(4)$, so we have
$$0=u_x(0,t)+h~u(0,t)=\phi'(ct)+\psi'(-ct)+h(\phi'(ct)+\psi'(-ct))$$
$$-h=\frac{d(\phi(ct)+\psi(-ct))}{\phi(ct)+\psi(-ct)}.$$
Integrate $0$ to $ct$,
$$-h(ct)+k_1=ln(\phi(ct)+\psi(-ct))~~~~~~~\text{where}~k_1=ln(\phi(0)+\psi(0))$$
$$\phi(ct)+\psi(-ct)=k~e^{-h(ct)}~~~~~~~\text{where}~k=\phi(0)+\psi(0)$$
Let $\alpha=-ct$.
$$\psi(\alpha)=k~e^{-h\alpha}-\phi(-\alpha)$$
Replacing $\alpha$ by $x-ct$,
$$\psi(x-ct)=k~e^{(ct-x)h}-\phi(ct-x)$$.
Hence,
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x+ct)-f(ct-x)\right)+ke^{(ct-x)}h.~~~~~(9)$$

Equation $(8)$ and $(9)$ together form solution.

State the compatibility condition of $f$.
 What to show for compatibility.